# Selenium @FindBy linkText or @FindBy partialLinkText not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, findby

I'm working for automation, I'm trying to click on an element ,this element has no id, classname so I'm using the xpath. To improve my code I would like to find this element by href, so I'm using:

```
@FindBy(linkText="Transfer")
WebElement transferBtn;
```

I also tried with:

```
@FindBy(partialLinkText="Transfer")
WebElement transferBtn;
```

But my code doesn't find the webElement, it's working for other href but not all. I think the problem is developer tools, i'll show you the element:

```
<a href="#">My transfer</a>
```

Do you have any idea of the problem, why it's not working?
Thanks.

Comment: The real issue I think is you should use "transfer" instead of "Transfer" in your `partialLinkText`.

Comment: linkText and href attribute are **not** the same thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared you can use either of the following solutions:

- `linkText`:

  ```
  @FindBy(linkText = "My transfer")
  WebElement transferBtn;
  ```
- `partialLinkText`:

  ```
  @FindBy(partialLinkText = "transfer")
  WebElement transferBtn;
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath  = "//a[contains(.,'My transfer')]")
  WebElement transferBtn;
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Change `Transfer` to `My transfer`

```
@FindBy(linkText="My transfer")
WebElement transferBtn;
```

OR
Change `Transfer` to `transfer`

```
@FindBy(partialLinkText="transfer")
WebElement transferBtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='My transfer']");
WebElement Transferbtn;
```